# Laravel randomly losing mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I have a laravel 6 project built upon http://laravel-boilerplate.com/ which I recently deployed on a shared 1&1 server. It's working absolutely fine but randomly loses connection to the mysql database :

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1)

This never happens locally, the error occurs every now and then on the 1&1 server. (I have many other projects on this server, never had this issue before). What could be wrong here ?

Comment: Do you have another project sharing same database?

Comment: No just one project.

Comment: perhaps changing DB_HOST in the .env file from 127.0.0.1 to localhost might fix it.

Comment: No...1&1 servers expect DB_HOST to be set to something like xxx..hosting-data.io though you're right it looks like it randomly loses settings from env file

Comment: If it could be possible that issue is something with `.env` file, try to set up fallback arguments in `config/database.php` and check if you loose connection under similar conditions. Again just to determine if something fishy is upon `.env` file.

Comment: This sounds to me like you are exceeding the connection count limit on your MySql server. Check whether your php/laravel program correctly releases its database connections when you're done using them.

Comment: Setting fallback arguments doesn't fix it. I now got a different error 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared (SQL: select * from `users` where `id` = 1 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1). Again this is random..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally issue resolved itself..very strange..It never occurred the next day and it’s been fine since..maybe related to being hosted on a shared server.